# How to extent event type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want one of my inputs to be able only assign values of certain strings (Vehicle brands in this case). On the Select component below I want the event type to only accept this 4 strings. How can I do that? How should I type myEventType?

```
......
    const [brand, setBrand] = useState<"All" | "Toyota" | "Ford" | "BMW">("All")

    type myCurrentTarget = Override<react.SyntheticEvent.currentTarget, { value: "All" | "Toyota" | "Ford" | "BMW" }>
    type myEventtype = Override<react.SyntheticEvent, myCurrentTarget>


......

return (
               <Select
                    value={brand}
                    onChange={e:myEventtype => setBrand(e.currentTarget.value)}
                    data={["All", "Toyota", "Ford", "BMW"]}
                />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**create an interface.**

Please refer below lines

```js
type valueType= "All" | "Toyota" | "Ford" | "BMW";
interface myEventtype{
    currentTarget:{
        value: valueType,
        [key:string]:any
    },
    [key:string]:any
}

return (
           <Select
                value={brand}
                onChange={e:myEventtype => setBrand(e.currentTarget.value)}
                data={["All", "Toyota", "Ford", "BMW"]}
            />
)
```

Comment: This is what I got:     Type '(e: myEventtype) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>'.
     Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
       Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to type 'myEventtype'.
         The types of 'currentTarget.value' are incompatible between these types.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a type to hold values of your vehicle brands like this: 
`type Brand = "All" | "Toyota" | "Ford" | "BMW";`

Change your state hook like this: 
`const [brand, setBrand] = useState<Brand>("All");`

Then define your custom event like this:

```js
type myEventtype = React.SyntheticEvent<{
  value: Brand;
}>;
```